# how can i get bold string from file and make as array key in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I uploaded the word file. I want to get bold text from that file. I want this text as key of the array. How to explode this file?

Comment: I don't know how to explode.I only uploaded the file. I want to convert files to xml, that's why I asked this question

Comment: Some of us are not psychics and would like to see the code related to question.